# Use 7z to backup each sub-directory to a separate file

Tags: command-line, 7za

My file structure is:

```
c:\csdata\folder1
c:\csdata\folder2
c:\csdata\folder3
etc
```

I'm trying to use 7z to backup all folders in `csdata` to their own archive to a temp folder (C:\butemp).

Here' what I have so far:

```
For /D %%i in (C:\csdata\*.*) DO 7za a "%%i.7z" "%%i"
```

The above works, but it creates the 7z file in the `csdata` folder, because `%%i` is equal to the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` gives you the ability to extract (and combine) various parts from the loop variable 
(taken from `help for`):

> %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
>       %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
>       (truncated)

```
The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

%~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
%~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
(truncated)
```

So you could use `7za a "C:\butemp\%%~nxi.7z" "%%i"`

Run `help for` for more options